# Automate MS project

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

Is there a way that we can automate the input in ms project 2010. Below are the scenarios:

1. We have a vb.net application that uses to inputs task name, hours, estimate and completion date time.
2. Is there a way that we can upload those date in ms project 2010.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. If you use desktop version of MS Project (Pro or Standard) then the only option you have is to use OLE automation.

Through the OLE Automation you will get a reference to an instance of Application class which is key class in every MS Office application. From the Application you can get a list of currently open projects using `Application.Projects` collection or even get current project using `Application.ActiveProject`.

As soon as you have a reference to a project you can access all tasks in the project using `Project.Tasks` collection. (Index of all collections starts with 1)

The most of Task fields like Name or Start date are available through properties of a Task: `Task.Name = "something"` or `Task.StartDate = "1/1/2001"`

Anyway here is a link: [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863668%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Another story is if you have Project Server and you want to do all the things faster. In this case you should use PSI (Project Server Interface) - collection of web services which give you access to the most of Project Server functions.

MSDN has great articles with samples how to work with projects using PSI and here is a link: [MSDN about PSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcproject.project_di_pj14mref_methods%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You can search around the link to find more articles about other services available through PSI.

Comment: Yes, I do. But what kind of technology do you plan to use and sample of what do you expect to see? You know I don't want to post here hundreds lines of code here to cover all possible cases :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're able to put your data into Excel as mentioned in your comment, then it would be fairly straightforward to write a VBA program that reads the excel data and updates the Project tasks with the data in the workbook.

Comment: Please add more details. Your answer currently looks like a comment (and would actually fit as a comment).